# Running Wires in Electrical Panel

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

Due to the design of this old Bryant electrical panel there is limited space to run wires. Common sense tells me it’s not a good idea but was curious if there’s anything in the electrical code that says insulated wires can’t pass over the hot bus. Would be nice to swing a couple of the larger wires around the right side of breakers. [image]

Comment: Sometimes common sense is better than the code.  The code usually spells out the minimum standard.

Comment: you already have bunch of wires crossing on the left side.

Comment: Do you have the owners’ manual for the panel? Code compliance includes following all manufacturer’s instructions.

Answer (score 5):

That's a code rule I haven't seen in an age. No, you can't cross the panel's breaker area with wires, but there's no chance of that since the panel is full and double-stuffed.

Coming around the right side shouldn't be a problem **with insulated wires**. Don't even think of doing it with a bare ground - yikes!

Really you should be thinking about where in the future you'd like to have a subpanel inside the house that will have a "working space" that is naturally kept clear (e.g. it's in a hall or threshold).  Maybe a 200A bussed subpanel.  The first round of upgrades you could feed it from this panel with a 50-100A breaker.  The next round, you could replace this panel with a meter-main and make the subpanel the primary panel for all loads.  40-space is the minimum size I would consider for an entire home.